# Ошибка в формуле рандомайзера

Tags: java, android

Сделал рандомайзер, но вижу, что ошибка в формуле - неправильные числа выдает.

```
int a = 0;
int oti = Integer.parseInt(ots);
int doi = Integer.parseInt(dos);

a = (int) (a - Math.random() * (doi - oti));

otvet.setText(String.valueOf(a));
```

Я хочу, чтобы рандомные числа генерировались между `oti` и `doi`. Лучше, чтобы входили обе границы

Comment: a читаю просто так, также могу дать полный код, сейчас

Comment: Я понимаю, но вы спрашивали про oti и doi, я полный код вам дал

Comment: ot - число от которого должны начинаться рандомные числа, do - до которого. Я хочу, чтобы были рандомные числа генерировались между ot и do. ots и тд. - стринг, oti - int.

Comment: и вам нужно отрицательное число?

Comment: да, лучше, чтобы входили

Comment: отрицательное не нужно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Случайное число от `oti` до `doi`, включая обе границы:

```
int a = (int)(Math.random() * (doi - oti + 1)) + oti;
```

Случайное число от `oti` до `doi`, включая только границу `oti`:

```
int a = (int)(Math.random() * (doi - oti)) + oti;
```

Comment: отлично, спасибо большое

Comment: альтернатива   int a=(int)Math.floor((Math.random()*doi)+oti);

Comment: @SupinePandora43 нет, `random * doi + oti` будет работать неправильно и выдавать результаты от `oti` до `oti + doi`.

Comment: у меня этот код с int отлично работает.  и входит в мою 'библиотеку'(просто 1 класс с тонной кода) для андроида

Comment: @SupinePandora43 [вот пример](https://ideone.com/YxKjd1) того, что ваш вариант работает неправильно. Вы уверены в "отлично"?